# AngularJs : "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling with following error since last 2 hours. I dont know whats wrong.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at eval (<anonymous>)
at Function.globalEval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js:4:4228)
at init.domManip (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js:5:20866)
at init.append (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js:5:18502)
at init.<anonymous> (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js:5:19874)
at Function.access (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js:4:5765)
at init.html (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js:5:19537)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8887/js/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:24156)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js:16:71
at ta (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js:84:35) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I could only find that this occurs when i call an angjs service

```
    app.factory("Userservice", ['$rootScope', '$http', 'GENERAL_CONFIG', 'FlashService',
    function($rootScope, $http, GENERAL_CONFIG, FlashService) {
        return {
            FindUserDetail: function(userid) {
                return $http.get(String.format('{0}/GetUserDetailById?UserId={1}',
                    GENERAL_CONFIG.ServiceWebApiUrl,
                    userid));
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Following is my controller code

```
    var userId = loggedIn.userId;
            Userservice.FindUserDetail(userId).then(//this line throws error
                function(data) {
                    if (data.data != null || data.data != undefined) {
                      var a = data.data.myJsonVariable //I get valid data here
                    }
                },
                function(httperror) {
                    FlashService.Error("Error Status Is " + httperror.status, true);
                });
```

Unexpected end of input is very generic error.
Guide me.

Comment: It appears to be throwing when jquery is parsing the response of your call to `GetUserDetailById`. It is probably returning an incomplete or invalid json string. Can you [edit] to add in the response coming from the server for this call?

Comment: The json response is complete. When I parse the response in json editor, its complete. Parsed without any errors. Even inside the success function i can access the json object. Like data.data.myJsonVariable

Comment: are you calling this as soon as this page/controller is instantiated? or is this returned in some function?

Comment: Where are you getting `String.format` from ? Have you extended the prototype?

Comment: If you want help with this error, you'll need to provide the JSON from the response, as it is shown in the Network tab of the browser's Developer Tools. Feel free to edit out confidential information, of course. However, the error is referring to the problem indicated by @Rhumborl. Without that information we cannot "guide you".

Comment: String.format is a custom function. Yes prototype extended.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to form `string` based on variable value. Where you're trying to utilize `String.Format` function of C#. `String.Format` wouldn't be available inside JavaScript. Or might have missed to extend `String` prototype.

You could do use Template Literal of ES6 here

```
return {
 FindUserDetail: function(userid) {
   return $http.get(`${GENERAL_CONFIG.ServiceWebApiUrl}/GetUserDetailById?UserId=${userid}`);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs throws this exception if you use it for repeating elements and miss something on the HTML side.

In my case, `<a href="javascript:void" class="btn yellow-crusta" ng-click="addItem()"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>` gave the exception.

Then I realized that I needed to end the element, just like it said.

So adding "; (semicolon)" to the end of and removing "void" from the href tag, as there was no function with the name "void" to call, did the job.

`<a href="javascript:;" class="btn yellow-crusta" ng-click="addItem()"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>`